# Favorite questions badge should not be shown for Community♦ pokes

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, community-user, favorites-tab

When favorite questions have activity, the red badge shows on the 'favorites' button on my profile:

[image]

However, this also shows when Community♦ pokes the question:

[image]

I use the badge on the button to be notified about updates to questions that I've favorited and I don't need to know when Community♦ pokes the question. Could the badge reflect the number of questions that have actually been changed?