# What does "modified 17m ago Community♦ 1" mean

Tags: support, edits, community-user, bump

Recently found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600789/hover-image-enlarge-using-css-in-front-of-other-images) "modified 17m ago Community♦ 1".
I can't understand how Community♦ modified it - he didn't edit it, nor its answers.
He didn't poke it, if did, it would be written "poked" instead of "modified", isn't it?
[image]

So  what does "modified" mean?

Comment: was it a poke, maybe?

Comment: Why do you think it would be written "poked"? [The only terms that are used in representing the last activity are "asked", "answered" and "modified".](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229665/)

Comment: 'if did, it would be written "poked" instead of "modified"' - would it? The stack app was doing it, but this information is now served directly from the server. And the question definitely satisfied the criteria for poking before it was upvoted today.

Comment: @JanDvorak Edited.

Comment: @Antony Edited.

Comment: Did you happen to use [my userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/4134/stack-activity-last-activity-of-every-question)?

Comment: @Antony I remembered that I saw "poked" [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225900/favorite-questions-badge-should-not-be-shown-for-community-pokes) and somewhere else...

Comment: @nicael The last activity does not show up on the favorites tab. The post you linked most likely involved a userscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was bumped by automatic process so that it has another chance to get attention, since it's not considered "answered" yet. (0 scored, non accepted answer is probably not good enough)

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped):

> The Community user will bump non-negatively scored questions that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that. The number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site: 4 per hour on Stack Overflow, 1 per hour on Meta, and 2 per hour on Super User and Server Fault. The default for a new site is 1 per hour.

You are right that nothing was really modified in the question, this is an artificial change of the "last activity" timestamp of the question, but changing the wording isn't that important in my opinion.

Now that you know how it works, feel free to start new feature request asking to change "modified" to something else in case of auto bumping, but like I said, not sure it will be implemented.

Comment: The userscript used "poked". Any idea how?

Comment: @Jan what userscript? What did it poke?

Comment: @JanDvorak I wrote [that userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/4134/stack-activity-last-activity-of-every-question). It was a guess work. When there is no real last activity on the post (no edits, no new answers, no bounties, no nothing) and the user is called Community♦, it assumes that it is poked. It would be more reliable if this is done on server side, but they have decided not to do it in the end.

Comment: @Antony there are also reopen, undelete and migrate events, all change the question's last active timestamp thus causing a bump which is not a "poke". All of them are present in the revisions list so best way to know question was auto bumped is checking the revisions list: no revision with same time means auto bump. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have accounted for reopen and migration events in the userscript as well. The most common false positive is when someone spams a question and the user gets removed. This causes Community♦ to take over as the last user with no visible activity left on the post.